# How to extract list from list of lists when any one element match with another list's element?

Tags: python

I am again stuck with extract and compare list elements.

I have following list of lists:

```
list = [['laravel', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 1.0, 3615],
 ['php', 1.0, 1405],
 ['php', 1.0, 5175],
 ['php', 1.0, 5176], 
 ['php', 1.0, 54], 
 ['php', 1.0, 5252],
 ['php', 1.0, 5279],
 ['python', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54],
 ['python',0.8333333333333334, 3615]]
```

we can see ID 54 have 3 skills (laravel,python,php) and 3615 have 2 skills

Now, My Desire output as below:

```
[{
  id :54
  No_matched_skills: 3
  skills: laravel,python,php
},
{
  id : 3615
  No_matched_skills : 2
  skills: laravel,python
}]
```

Can anyone please tell me how can I do?

Comment: Removed the part where ou ask for tutorials in order not for you to get this question closed. Also, please provide something you tried.

Comment: Is your output supposed to be console output? It is not a valid Python literal.

Comment: I think the intermediate data structure you should look for is a dictionary with the `id` for the keys, and the list of skill for the values: `{54:['laravel','python','php'], 3615:['laravel','python'], .... }`

Comment: I notice that user 54 has two "laravel" skill entries. Is that intentional? Should user 54 be considered to have four skills (laravel, laravel, python, php) or three (laravel, python, php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your variable name from `list` to `lists` because while `list` is not a reserved keyword, you'd be overwriting the keyword for the list data structure.

```
lists = [['laravel', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 1.0, 3615],
 ['php', 1.0, 1405],
 ['php', 1.0, 5175],
 ['php', 1.0, 5176], 
 ['php', 1.0, 54], 
 ['php', 1.0, 5252],
 ['php', 1.0, 5279],
 ['python', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54],
 ['python',0.8333333333333334, 3615]]

skills = {}

for l in lists:
  skill, _, id = l
  if id in skills:
    skills[id].append(skill)
  else:
    skills[id] = [skill]

output = []
for k in skills.keys():
  output.append({
    "id": k,
    "No_matched_skills": len(skills[k]),
    "skills": ",".join(skills[k])
  })

print(output)
```

Let's look at this line by line:

```
skills = {}
```

Create a new dictionary so that for each unique ID in the `lists` variable, we can store a list of skills.

```
for l in lists:
  skill, _, id = l
  if id in skills:
    skills[id].append(skill)
  else:
    skills[id] = [skill]
```

Not sure what that middle variable is so I used `_` as its variable name. Change as needed.

I'm using the line `skill, _, id = l` to unpack the list `l` into those variables.

If I find the current `id` in the `skills` dictionary, I just go ahead and use `list.append()` to add it to the existing list. Otherwise, I create new list in place with the current skill.

```
output = []
for k in skills.keys():
  output.append({
    "id": k,
    "No_matched_skills": len(skills[k]),
    "skills": ",".join(skills[k])
  })
```

For each key in the `skills` dictionary, I append a dictionary to the `output` list. The `id` is simply the key, `No_matched_skills` is the size of the list for that key, and I use `",".join(skills[k])` to take that list and save it as a comma-separated string.

Comment: Thank you for you Reply. I tried like this but I don't know I got blank dictionary after IF statement But you clear my confusion because I didn't give else statement. 
Anyway Thank you so much for your explanation and answer

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

l = [['laravel', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 1.0, 3615],
 ['php', 1.0, 1405],
 ['php', 1.0, 5175],
 ['php', 1.0, 5176], 
 ['php', 1.0, 54], 
 ['php', 1.0, 5252],
 ['php', 1.0, 5279],
 ['python', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54],
 ['python',0.8333333333333334, 3615]]

o = []
for key, grp in groupby(sorted(l, key=itemgetter(2)), key=itemgetter(2)):
    skills = [l[0] for l in grp]
    o.append({"id": key, "no_matched_skills": len(skills), "skills": skills})
o
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 54,
  'no_matched_skills': 4,
  'skills': ['laravel', 'php', 'python', 'laravel']},
 {'id': 1405, 'no_matched_skills': 1, 'skills': ['php']},
 {'id': 3615, 'no_matched_skills': 2, 'skills': ['laravel', 'python']},
 {'id': 5175, 'no_matched_skills': 1, 'skills': ['php']},
 {'id': 5176, 'no_matched_skills': 1, 'skills': ['php']},
 {'id': 5252, 'no_matched_skills': 1, 'skills': ['php']},
 {'id': 5279, 'no_matched_skills': 1, 'skills': ['php']}]
```

Comment: I like the idea of using groupby, but I'm not sure the output is correct. I think the OP wanted "no_matched_skills" to be 3 for user 54, even though there are four entries for user 54 in the original list.

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
d = dd(set)
skillList = [['laravel', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 1.0, 3615],
 ['php', 1.0, 1405],
 ['php', 1.0, 5175],
 ['php', 1.0, 5176], 
 ['php', 1.0, 54], 
 ['php', 1.0, 5252],
 ['php', 1.0, 5279],
 ['python', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54],
 ['python',0.8333333333333334, 3615]]
for i in skillList:
    d[i[2]].add(i[0])
temp = [ {'id':i,'No_matched_skills':len(d[i]),'skills':','.join(d[i])} for i in d if len(d[i])>1]
print temp
```

This will remove repetitions and only show those which have more than one skill

Output:

```
[{'skills': 'laravel,python,php', 'No_matched_skills': 3, 'id': 54}, 
{'skills': 'laravel,python', 'No_matched_skills': 2, 'id': 3615}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using '`Counter`' and '`defaultdict`' from Python:

```
l = [['laravel', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 1.0, 3615],
 ['php', 1.0, 1405],
 ['php', 1.0, 5175],
 ['php', 1.0, 5176],
 ['php', 1.0, 54],
 ['php', 1.0, 5252],
 ['php', 1.0, 5279],
 ['python', 1.0, 54],
 ['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54],
 ['python',0.8333333333333334, 3615]]

from pprint import pprint
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

c = Counter(i[2] for i in l)

d = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
for i in l:
    if c[i[2]] > 1:
        d[i[2]][i[0]] += 1

rv = []
for k, v in d.items():
    rv.append({'id': k, 'No_matched_skills': len(v), 'skills': [*v]})

pprint(rv, width=10)
```

Output:

```
[{'No_matched_skills': 3,
  'id': 54,
  'skills': ['laravel',
             'php',
             'python']},
 {'No_matched_skills': 2,
  'id': 3615,
  'skills': ['laravel',
             'python']}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this,

```
my_list = [['laravel', 1.0, 54],
['laravel', 1.0, 3615],
['php', 1.0, 1405],
['php', 1.0, 5175],
['php', 1.0, 5176], 
['php', 1.0, 54], 
['php', 1.0, 5252],
['php', 1.0, 5279],
['python', 1.0, 54],
['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54],
['python',0.8333333333333334, 3615]]

compute_dict = {}
for l in my_list:
    compute_dict.setdefault(l[2], [])
    compute_dict[l[2]].append(l[0])

final_list = []

for k,v in compute_dict.items():
    final_list.append({"id":k,"No_matched_skills":len(set(v)),"skills":", ".join(set(v))})
```

Basically, the first step is to create a dictionary with IDs as keys and programming language as values. Therefore, `compute_dict` will look like

```
>>> {54: ['laravel', 'php', 'python', 'laravel'], 3615: ['laravel','python'], 1405: ['php'], 5175: ['php'], 5176: ['php'], 5252: ['php'], 5279: ['php']}
```

So, from there were able to create a list with the expected output. Note that I'm using `set()` in order to remove duplicates from the original dict.

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy using a 3rd party library, you can use Pandas. Given a list `L`:

```
import pandas as pd

# construct dataframe from list
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['skills', 'value', 'id'])

# define aggregation functions
funcs = {'No_matched_skills': 'nunique', 'skills': lambda x: ', '.join(x.unique())}

# apply groupby and convert to dictionary
res = df.groupby('id', as_index=False)['skills'].agg(funcs).to_dict('records')

print(res)

[{'No_matched_skills': 3, 'id': 54, 'skills': 'laravel, php, python'},
 {'No_matched_skills': 1, 'id': 1405, 'skills': 'php'},
 {'No_matched_skills': 2, 'id': 3615, 'skills': 'laravel, python'},
 {'No_matched_skills': 1, 'id': 5175, 'skills': 'php'},
 {'No_matched_skills': 1, 'id': 5176, 'skills': 'php'},
 {'No_matched_skills': 1, 'id': 5252, 'skills': 'php'},
 {'No_matched_skills': 1, 'id': 5279, 'skills': 'php'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
import itertools
_list = [['laravel', 1.0, 54], ['laravel', 1.0, 3615], ['php', 1.0, 1405], ['php', 1.0, 5175], ['php', 1.0, 5176], ['php', 1.0, 54], ['php', 1.0, 5252], ['php', 1.0, 5279], ['python', 1.0, 54], ['laravel', 0.8333333333333334, 54], ['python', 0.8333333333333334, 3615]]
new_list = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(_list, key=lambda x:x[-1]), key=lambda x:x[-1])]
final_result = [{'id':a, 'No_matched_skills':len(b), 'skills':[c for c, *_ in b]} for a, b in new_list]
filtered = list(filter(lambda x:x['No_matched_skills'] > 1, final_result))
```

Output:

```
[{'id': 54, 'No_matched_skills': 4, 'skills': ['laravel', 'php', 'python', 'laravel']}, {'id': 3615, 'No_matched_skills': 2, 'skills': ['laravel', 'python']}]
```